# "心中" as "in mind"?

Tags: middle-chinese

I am looking at a definition for 心中 that reads: "noun: in mind".

To me, the English phrase "in mind", I don't really think of it as a noun, what does it mean to be a noun that means "in mind", does it refer to the state of something so much as it is "in mind"? If so, wouldn't there be a much better word to describe that?

How does the character 心 "mind" relate to its partner, 中 (in, among, centre, etc) to form this compound two-part character that stands for a "noun meaning 'in mind'"?

Comment: if online please supply link to  dictionary，bkrs:
心中
[in the heart; at heart; in mind] 心里
内心(heart
innermost being
(math.) incenter) central point
in one’s thoughts
in one’s heart
at heart; in mind

Comment: for 心中 w/o 在 in front enter 心中 into jukuu to get 100 sample sentences, just checking 1-10 and 91-100, 1-8 do not have 在, 9,10 do have it, 91-100 do not have 在

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to translate it as a full noun phrase such as "the inside of your mind" to help your understanding.

心中 is more of written Chinese.

I bet you found the word 心中 from a song or poem etc since it is rarely used in a daily conversation. A colloquial synonym is 心里 which has the same meaning, where 里 means inside (for example, 里面 inside)

Sometimes you can also hear people saying 心里面 (the inside of your mind) which is more spoken form.

Answer (score 1):

you better to add `在` before, like `在心中` to make this a complete phase, and which means `in mind`

Answer (score 0):

As an example, 心中 can be used as in the phrase "记在心中," which translates to "keep in mind."

If one says "I will keep this in mind," the Chinese version can be “我会把这个记在心中。”

Literally, this would be "I will put this into my mind/heart。”

“心” is “mind/heart” and “中” is “in” or, in this context, “into.”

Here, the "mind/heart" is in noun form. That's why "心中" is described as a noun in your definition.